# Google Drive Find and Replace api

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I need to do something very simple with Google Docs/ Google drive :
I need to replace certain words within a Google docs document with another word on a large scale.

Currently I download the files as html, make the changes locally and upload the updated files again. Seems like a huge process for something rather simple.

Is there a way I can do this an HTTP request? Will this be supported by the API in the future?

Thanks,

Comment: You might want to have a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627356/how-to-use-method-replacetextsearchpattern-replacement-in-documents-service) that shows how it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Document services in Apps Script to easily replace text in your documents:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_document#replaceText

Comment: is replaceText still available? Unable to find that in link