# Need to edit gdoc using a googleappscript

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible that I could add the body of a gdoc into an email? I kinda have an idea of how to do it but I am not completely sure. I have written this code below to kinda help me. I am new to this and I have managed to have a few scripts running, but I am completely lost on this one. I have watched several videos and this is what I was able to do. The code is below.
Basically what I want to do is to be able to have a user input his name and another variable and then go to the google doc file and change it to the value that was input and then put it back in an email and send it to an address... Any ideas of what I am doing wrong or where should I start?? Thanks in advance.

```
function gsnot() {
var emailaddress="albdominguez25@gmail.net";
var sub="Subject1";
var pattern = Browser.inputBox("Enter your name");
var pattern2 = Browser.inputBox("Enter the minutes:");
var templateDocID= ScriptProperties.getProperty("EmailTemplateDocId");
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(templateDocID);
  var body = doc.getActiveSection()
var html = "";


var keys = {
name: pattern, 
min: pattern2,
};

for ( var k in keys ) {
body.replaceText("%" + k + "%", keys[k]);

doc.saveAndClose();
html = getDocAsHtml(docId);
DocsList.getFileById(docId).setTrashed(true);

return html;

var emailaddress="albdominguez25@gmail.net";
var sub="Subject1";

MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress,sub, {htmlBody: body});}}
```

Comment: here is the link for the doc I am trying to edit and email https://docs.google.com/a/infolinksa.net/document/d/13AuhHPjOPijHIILasWho3tUvyuIK1GtCXWuxZe7RscA/edit

Comment: there are some strange lines in your code... where does getDocAsHtml() come from ? is it another function in your script ?

Comment: As for the replacement, have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627356/how-to-use-method-replacetextsearchpattern-replacement-in-documents-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to change your code by reading the body from the document into a variable, doing the replace on the variable and inserting that into your email. For example:

```
function gsnot() {
  var emailaddress = "albdominguez25@gmail.net";
  var sub = "New Subject";
  var pattern  = Browser.inputBox("Enter your name:");
  var pattern2 = Browser.inputBox("Enter the minutes:");
  var templateDocID = ScriptProperties.getProperty("EmailTemplateDocId");
  var doc  = DocumentApp.openById(templateDocID);
  var body = doc.getText();
  var replacement;
  var k;

  var keys = {
    name: pattern, 
    min:  pattern2
  };

  for (k in keys) {
    if (keys.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      replacement = new RegExp("%" + k + "%",'g');
      body = body.replace(replacement, keys[k]);
    }
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailaddress,sub, '', {htmlBody: body});
}
```

A few notes:

- It is good form to have all your var statements at the beginning of
  the function
- When you use for-in (eg. for (k in keys) ), it returns all properties of the object. You only want the ones you assigned. This is the reason for: for (k in keys)
- You had the mail sending for each property, I believe you wanted it outside the for-in loop so it only sent after all the replacements were completed.
- Using replace(), you need to create a regular expression object that is set to global
  or it will only replace the first instance of the pattern (you have name twice).
- In your parameters for sendEmail(), even if you are using the htmlBody option, you need to specify a plain text body. I used empty quotes ''.