# Send emails from google spreadsheet - coding suggestions

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am still learning the ropes here. Based on code suggested by other contributors, I put together a script to send reminder emails to consultants who record their time entries using a Google Form. The spreadsheet first imports calendar entries with all the Job information for each consultant. After the calendar entries are imported, if the consultant has not yet recorded their time entry, the following script will send them an email with a reminder to do so:

```js
function sendReminder() {

  var rmndrFrom = "XYZ, Inc.";
  var myemail   = "support@xyz.com";

  var sheet     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Pending");
  var numRows   = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol   = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows, lastCol); // row 1 is the header row
  var sheetData = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetData.length; ++i) {
    var row = sheetData[i];
    if (row[0]){
      var jobNumb = row[0]; // Job Number
      var conName = row[2]; // Consultant Name
      var conMail = row[3]; // Consultant Email
      var jobDate = row[4]; // Date

      // format email string
      var subject = "Time Entry Reminder: " + conName + " / Job " + jobNumb;

        try {
          var conMsgH = 'This is a reminder for you to record your time entry for Job #<strong>' + jobNum + '/' + jobDate + '</strong>';

          // strip HTML for plain text message
          var conMsgP = conMsgH.replace(/\<br\/\>/gi, '\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");

          // send reminder to consultants
          MailApp.sendEmail(conMail, subject, conMsgP, { htmlBody:conMsgH, name:rmndrFrom });

        } catch (e) { // error handler
          MailApp.sendEmail(myemail, "Error in sending reminder email.", e.message);
        }
      }
  }
}
```

So basically, this script parses the Pending sheet, if column A has a Job Number, it will send a reminder email to the consultant with that Job Number. However, a single consultant may have several job numbers to their name. I would like the script to send a single email to each consultant with a list of the Job Numbers for which they have to record their time entries.

Thanks in advance for your kind help. Any suggestions on how to optimize the code will also be very much appreciated.

Comment: Also consider the posibility to use an Email template using   `ScriptProperties.getProperty("EmailTemplate")`. It is pretty clean, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093511/need-to-edit-gdoc-using-a-googleappscript) you can find an example. And look [here](http://www.cloudtouch.co.uk/2012/03/04/an-introduction-to-google-apps-script-part-2-send-emails-using-spreadsheets-gmail-and-a-document-template/) to find out how to add the template to your script!

Comment: Thank you for this fantastic suggestion @Jacobvdb! It will fit perfectly in the next aspect of my spreadsheet/script adventure: sending automatic reports. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways that you can approach this. One way is to keep a sheet with the consultants emails, names and a list of their job numbers. Load this data into your script, a list of all job ids and the job info. Then filter the job ids based on the consultants list and build your email, or you could just send that list of numbers for a very short script.

Another way is to do all of that sorting per consultant in the code and send out the emails that way. This is the approach I've taken, and I've also made use of the iterative JS functions map, filter and reduce [more details at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

The code is posted below, but if you would like to take a look at it attached to a spreadsheet and commented (as well as the functions to build that extra sheet with just the consultants info on it) take a look [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Amf6KahEwgTbdDFfQmJFRWVVX2gweHlpaVhKcnhoa0E#gid=1).

Below is my iteration of your function. I hope it is helpful for your situation:

```
var rmndrFrom = "XYZ, Inc.";
var myemail   = "me@emailisawesome.com";
var subject   = "Time Entry Reminder";

function sendReminder() {
  var sheet       = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Pending");
  var numRows     = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol     = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var sheetData   = sheet.getRange(2, 1, numRows-1, lastCol).getValues();
  var cons = sheet.getRange(2,3,numRows-1,1).getValues().reduce(flatten_).filter(getUniqueConsultants_);
  cons.forEach(sendEmail_, sheetData);
}

function sendEmail_(consultant) {
  var consultantsJobs = this.filter(getJobsForConsultant_, consultant);
  var jobList = consultantsJobs.map(buildJobLine_).join("<br>"); 
  try {
    var conMsgH = "Hi " + consultant + ",<br>";
    conMsgH    += "This is a reminder for you to record your time entry for the following jobs:<br><br>";
    conMsgH    += jobList;
    conMsgH    += "<br><br>Thank you for your cooperation.";
    var conMsgP = conMsgH.replace(/\<br\/\>/gi, '\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "");
    MailApp.sendEmail(consultantsJobs[0][3], subject, conMsgP, {htmlBody:conMsgH, name:rmndrFrom});
  } catch (e) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(myemail, "Error in sending reminder email.", e.message);
  } 
}

function buildJobLine_(job) {
  return "Job #" + job[0] + " on " + Utilities.formatDate(job[4], Session.getTimeZone(), "MMM dd yyyy");
}

function getJobsForConsultant_(row) {
  return row[2] == this;
}

function getUniqueConsultants_(v,i,a) {
  return a.indexOf(v) == i;
}

function flatten_(a,b) {
  return a.concat(b);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this (free) "JS arrays" lesson, it took me some time to catch how it works but the link you provided was helpful ;-)

Comment: Fooby, your iteration of the script is enviable, to say the least. A special thank you for your commented script; it was very helpful in understanding how your script works and figuring out how to display additional information in the reminder email.

Comment: while testing I noticed that the text only version had a problem. The regex used for `<BR>` doesn't seem to work, I think there is an escape that shouldn't be there... I replaced by `.replace(/<br>/ig, '\n')` and it worked well.

Comment: Although my plain text version shows ok (in Gmail), thanks for pointing it out! Nonetheless, I followed your (much more straightforward) suggestion and it also works.

Comment: Thank you for the compliments. I did not test the regex nor plain text. Happy to help.

Comment: Hello again everyone! Thanks to all of your suggestions, my script has matured considerably, but yet to implement templates. Perhaps you can help me figure something out. I added "Rate" and "Total Billable" to the columns in my sheet. When sending out the reminders, consultants want to be reminded of how much the need to bill (this will also help me keep better track of what I need to bill myself and pay consultants). Is there a way that I can add up the totals to get a grand total to be billed per consultant before sending the reminder email? Thanks!

Comment: @walermo I'm not sure at what point support for a question is taken offline, but yes, there are easy ways to do this. However, I don't believe this is the right place for the conversation to continue. More experience members, please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I must say that [fooby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1384561/fooby)'s answer is far beyond my JS skills, I'm sure it will work nicely but I still feel like proposing something different (and simpler from my pov), just for the fun of it ;-)

The main difference with your original script is the sorting of the array that allowed me to detect duplicate names and threat it accordingly.  The html composition could be far better for sure but that was not your main request.

Here is the code

```
function sendReminder() {

  var rmndrFrom = "XYZ, Inc.";
  var myemail   = "support@xyz.com";
  var sheet     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Pending");
  var initial = "Hi conName,<BR>This is a reminder for you to record your time entry for the following jobs : <BR><BR><table border = 1 cellpadding = 3 bgcolor='#FFFFBB'><TR><TD>";

  var sheetData = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();// simplified code to get the data array
  sheetData.shift();//skips the headers
  sheetData.sort(function(x,y){
  var xp = x[2];// sort on column 3 but you can change  here...
  var yp = y[2];// sort on column 3 but you can change  here...
  return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;// sort ascending, eventually change here...
  });
//  Logger.log(sheetData);// sorted
  var last = sheetData.length
  var i = 1;//index 0 is handled outside the loop
  var row = sheetData[0];
  var subject = "Time Entry Reminder: " + row[2] + " / Job "
  var conMsgH = initial
  var msgComponent = makeline_(row)
  subject += msgComponent[0]
  conMsgH += msgComponent[1]

  while (i<last){
    if(sheetData[i][2]!=sheetData[i-1][2]||i==last-1){
      sendData_(sheetData[i-1][3],sheetData[i-1][2],subject,conMsgH)
      var subject = "Time Entry Reminder: " + sheetData[i][2] + " / Job "
  var conMsgH = initial;
      }
  msgComponent = makeline_(sheetData[i])
  subject += msgComponent[0]
  conMsgH += msgComponent[1]
  ++i
  }
}

function sendData_(conMail,conName,subject,conMsgH){
  conMsgH = conMsgH.substr(0,conMsgH.length-8)+'</TABLE>'
  conMsgH = conMsgH.replace('conName',conName)
  var conMsgP = conMsgH.replace(/<\/tr>/ig, '\n').replace(/<br>/ig, '\n').replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "")
  subject = subject.substr(0,subject.length-2);// remove the last '+ '
//  Logger.log(subject)
//  Logger.log(conMsgH)
  Logger.log(conMsgP)
//  Logger.log(conMail)
  try{
          // send reminder to consultants          
          MailApp.sendEmail(conMail, subject, conMsgP, { htmlBody:conMsgH, name:rmndrFrom });
        } catch (e) { // error handler
//          MailApp.sendEmail(myemail, "Error in sending reminder email.", e.message);
    }
}

function makeline_(row){
      var jobNumb = row[0]; // Job Number
      var conName = row[2]; // Consultant Name
      var conMail = row[3]; // Consultant Email
      var descr = row[1]; // description
      var FUS1=new Date(row[4]).toString().substr(25,6)+':00';// get timezone of this event, taking care of daylight savings
      var jobDate = Utilities.formatDate(row[4], FUS1, "MMM dd yyyy @ hh:mm aaa"); // Date
      var subject =  jobNumb+' + ';
      var conMsgH =  'Job #'+jobNumb + '</TD><TD>' + jobDate + '</TD><TD>' + descr + '</TD></TR><TR><TD>';
return [subject,conMsgH];
}
```

**EDIT :** made some improvement in the mail format, used a table to show jobs & dates + removed some bugs ;-) *(to be honest, I made this also for my personal use as I am having almost the same use case )*

Comment: Thank you also @Serge for your help. Because my original question was a stripped down version of the script I am using, your proposal was easier for me to follow. Suffice to say that my JS skills are novice, at best. However, it was easier for me to use @fooby's code to include `html` before and after the joblist.

Comment: no problem, I understand your pointof view, I guess I would have done the same some time ago (right now I find it quite pleasant to dig into this ;-)