# Copying selected row to presentation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My goal is to copy a row from a spreadsheet and merge the row data using markers into a document (ideally a google presentation) that saves as a PDF that I can print.

I have figured out how to have the selected row copied into an object, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get that text copied into any kind of temporary document. I have a presentation template with markers all ready to go.

Here is some of the scripts that I've been working with.

```
function printRepairs() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var row = sheet.getActiveSelection();

  //prints a comma delim string of a single row
  var row1 = data[1]
  Logger.log("row #1: " + row1);
  var selectedRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValues();

  // creates a file with selected row --doesn't work.
  Browser.msgBox("the row you selected contains: " +selectedRow);  
  DocsList.createFile('temp_row', selectedRow);
  copyblob(selectedRow);

  var folder = DocsList.getFolder('temp');
  folder.createFile('temp_row', 'hello', 'application/vnd.google-apps.document');

  doc = DocumentApp.create("sheet_test");
  DocumentApp.openById("sheet_test");
  text.insertText("sheet_test", selectedRow);

  Browser.msgBox("the row you selected contains: " +selectedRow);
  Logger.log("the row you selected contains: " + selectedRow);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation you're performing is commonly called a "mail merge" . There are Google Docs add-ons that can do this for you - from a Google Doc go to "Add-ons > Get add-ons" and search for "merge".

To do the same from your own script, I recommend you first get familiar with the material in the [Simple Mail Merge tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge). Instead of building an email from a template in a spreadsheet, you'll create a new document from a document template.

1. Create a google doc template, with markers that match the column headers in your spreadsheet.

   > I have a presentation template with markers all ready to go.

   Unfortunately, there's no support for presentations (yet). Star [Issue 1573: Presentation Service for Google Apps Script](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1573). (Maybe your vote will be the one that finally gets it done!)
2. For each row in your spreadsheet...

   1. Create a copy of the template doc. [`DriveApp.makeCopy(name, destination)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makeCopy(String,Folder)). You should use a unique name for each file, but if you don't you'll just end up with multiple files with the same name on Drive.
   2. Use the `fileId` of the new file, and open it as a document. [`DocumentApp.openById(id)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app#openById(String))
   3. Using a technique similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627356), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692669) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692669), search through the document for your markers, and replace with data from the spreadsheet.