# How can I perform a straight search and replace in a Google Doc?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to do a search and replace in a Google Doc using a Google Script. A straight text search and replace like available through the web interface.

The source doc contains [schoolname] as a placemarker and I want to make a copy of that original, then search and replace [schoolname] in the new document.

I tried replaceText("([schoolname])","sometext") after reading this thread: [How to use method replaceText(searchPattern, replacement) in documents Service/ text Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627356/how-to-use-method-replacetextsearchpattern-replacement-in-documents-service)

I double checked the regex through http://www.regexr.com/ to no avail

Should I be using some alternative to replaceText() or just fix the regex somehow? Thanks in advance.

Edit: code segment

```
var newfile = sourcefile.makeCopy();
newfile.setName(sourcefile.getName().replace("[schoolname]","replacementtext"));
var newdoc = DocumentApp.openById(newfile.getId());
var paras = newdoc.getBody().getParagraphs();
newdoc.getBody().replaceText("(\[schoolname\])","replacementtext");
```

Comment: Can you paster the code around the `replaceText`?

Comment: I've added a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found ReplaceText to be very erradic, instead of ([]) as delimiter, use %%, so tou don't have to escape.

Comment: Wow. That absolutely worked. I used `replaceText("%schoolname%","replacementtext")` and it worked as expected. Thanks @Kriggs